# System.Windows.Browser Windows Phone Maps app

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, bing-maps

Problem: I was following [this tutorial](http://www.earthware.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/03/writing-a-bing-maps-location-aware-application-for-windows-phone-7-series/) when I came across a problem.

It appears that you can no longer include `System.Windows.Browser` and without it, i get this error:

> Error  3   The type or namespace name 'Maps' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\project1\project1\obj\Debug\MainPage.g.i.cs 12  17

Under the reference itself, it says it can not be resolved. Is there a known workaround for this? I would like all the functionality of this tutorial if anyone knows of an alternative / better tutorial.

Running all the newest SDKs.

Comment: Are you targeting Mango? How does that sample application on the tutorial compile for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tutorial was for the wp7 beta SDK and only worked on the simulator.google for wp7 Bing maps tutorial and you should find a tutorial that's much newer